# How to solve an integral using the gamma distribution

Tags: statistics

I am asked to find E(Y) of the density function:

$f(y) = \frac{y^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{3}{4}\sqrt\pi}e^{-y},$ for $0<y<\infty$

So, by definition

E(Y)= $\int_0^\infty yf(y)dy = \int_0^\infty \frac{y^{\frac{5}{2}}}{\frac{3}{4}\sqrt\pi}e^{-y}$

How would I compute that integral without using "erf" (I do not even know what that is, so I doubt that in my evaluation we use it).

I can see the similarity on the gamma function, but I cannot solve the integral.
Like, how can I even start?

Comment: In fact, the distribution of $Y$ is a gamma distribution. You can check it out.

Comment: Why is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) not enough for you to solve this?

Comment: Can I say that $\alpha = \frac{5}{2}$ and $\beta = 1?$

Comment: @Juju9704 Right!

Comment: So, by a theorem, $E(Y)= \alpha \beta$ and $V(Y)= \alpha \beta^2$, the mean and avriance would be both $\frac{5}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the integral without using the formulae for the distribution simply notice that

$$E(Y)=\frac{1}{\frac{3}{4}\sqrt\pi}\int_0^\infty y^{7/2-1}e^{-y}\mathrm{d}y=\frac{4}{3\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma(7/2)=\frac{4}{3}\frac{15}{8}=\frac{5}{2}  $$

because $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt\pi$ and $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$

Comment: @Nosrati I inverted $3/4$ and $4/3$ in the whole calculation by mistake, corrected now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The PDF $f(y)$ is of a $\text{Gamma}(\alpha = 5/2, \beta=1)$ distribution, as you've mentioned in the comments. Note that $\Gamma(5/2) = (3/4)\sqrt{\pi}$.

Without resorting to the shortcut formulas, here's another way you can approach the problem.

Observe 
$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{y^{5/2}}{(3/4)\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-y}\text{ d}y\text{.}$$
Take into account that the integrand looks very, very similar to a $\text{Gamma}(\alpha= 7/2, \beta = 1)$ PDF, in which case

$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{y^{5/2}}{\Gamma(7/2)}e^{-y}\text{ d}y &= \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{y^{5/2}}{(5/2)\Gamma(5/2)}e^{-y}\text{ d}y \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{y^{5/2}}{(5/2)(3/4)\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-y}\text{ d}y\\
&=\dfrac{2}{5}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{y^{5/2}}{(3/4)\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-y}\text{ d}y \\
&= 1
\end{align}$$
because we are integrating a density function.
From simple algebra, we find that
$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{y^{5/2}}{(3/4)\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-y}\text{ d}y = \dfrac{5}{2}\text{.}$$